# UIScrollVewDelegate methods not invoked

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UITableview, a UITextField and a few other elements inside a UIScrollView. The scrollview has 'scrollEnabled' set to NO until the UITextField becomes first responder. My Controller class is also set to be a delegate of UIScrollView.

I can scroll up and down just fine as expected as soon 'scrollEnabled' is set to YES and I change the content size. But none of UIScrollViewDelegate methods are invoked once scrollEnabled.

ScrollView has 'User Interaction Enabled' turned on.

Is there anything else that need to be configured to get the delegate methods?

Comment: do your delegate methods ever get called? before scrollenabled for example? show the code where it links it please

Answer (score 0):

None of my delegate methods were getting invoked. But then I realized that I also had scrolling turned on the tableview that is a subview of the ScrollView. Turning it off adjusted to the expected behavior.